# ただいま～ at the beginning

Tags: grammar

I saw ただいま at the beginning of two expressions and I couldn't understand its meaning in the context.

> A : すみません。かいがいじぎょうかのぱくさん、おねがいしたいんですが。
>
> 受付：おやくそくですか。
>
> A : はい。
>
> 受付：ただいまおよびします。しょうしょうおまちください。
> もうしわけございません。ぱくはただいま電話中ですので、こちらでおまちください。

What do ただいまおよびします and ただいま電話中 mean?
And is there a rule about ただいま in grammar?

Answer (score 3):

I shall explain each word as I am not sure of your level, or how much of the sentence you understand.

> ただいまおよびします and ただいま電話中

およびします is a humble way to say よびます (polite) / よぶ (plain), to call (someone).
If you are unfamiliar with humble conjugations and keigo and you would like to learn more, please visit [this site](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/honorific) (hard!).

電話中 means currently on a call (電話{でんわ} phone; phone call + 中{ちゅう} currently).

ただいま, other than a greeting meaning "I'm home!", can also mean "right now". (See comment by Shoko below)

Putting it all together:

> ただいまおよびします
>
> *I will call ぱく right now.* (Edited)
>
> ただいま電話中
>
> *ぱく is currently on a call.*

---

> and is there a rule about ただいま in grammar ?

In these cases, ただいま is used in the sense of "right now", as an adverb. Adverbs often can be placed in many places in a sentence, but it is usually immediately to the left of **the word it is describing** (currently **calling** = ただいまおよびします; currently **on a call** ただいま**電話中**)

Comment: ただいま as an adverb can be used for an action in present, future and past. 「ただいま電話中」→ 今現在 currently (present),「ただいまお呼びします。」→今すぐ。すぐに。ただちに。right away (future), 「ただいまお帰りになりました。」→たった今。ついさっき。つい今しがた。just did (past)

Comment: I've edited my answer to try to reflect this better. Thank you!

Comment: @Chocolate Bit of a silly question but your explanation also applies for when it's used with station names too right? e.g 「ただいま、新大阪」as seen on the electronic board.

Comment: @Nubcake 「ただいまXX(駅)」 should be short for 「電車はただいまXX駅です/に停車中です/にいます。」"The train is at XX station now." The ただいま represents *present* and not *future* or *past*, meaning 今現在, "currently" or "now".

Answer (score 1):

According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> ただいま【只今】
>   〘副詞〙
>   ❶〘名詞〙まさに今。今現在。「ただいま準備中」
>   ❷〘名詞〙つい今しがた。「ただいまお帰りになりました」
>   ❸すぐに。もうすぐ。「はい。ただいま参ります」

ただいま can mean:

> 1. "right now" "now at this moment" "currently". Often used with 「Verb+ています」「XX[中]{ちゅう}」「XX[中]{ちゅう}です」
> 2. "a moment ago" "just now". Often used with 「Verb+ました」「Verb+たところです」
> 3. "right away" "at once" "immediately". Often used with 「Verb+ます」

ただいま in ただいまお呼びします means 3. "right away" "at once" "immediately", and ただいま in ただいま電話中です means 1. "right now" "now at this moment" "currently".

> ただいまお呼びします。I will call him *immediately*.
>   ただいま電話中です。 He is on another line *at the moment*.

---

As a side not, ただいま used in these meanings is pronounced [ただいま]{LHLL}.
ただいま as a greeting is pronounced [ただいま]{LHHH}.
<sub>(Though it might depend on the region; in Kansai I often hear it pronounced as [ただいま]{LHLH}.)</sub>