# What does ただいま Mean in the Context of Preparing Food?

Tags: meaning, usage

I heard it a couple of times after I thought that I understood it to mean "I'm home".

The other contexts I've heard it were in the context of preparing food either to go or right away, I wanted to know a more precise meaning.

Are there other contexts in which ただいま is used?

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44502/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3867/9831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ただいま" is commonly used as the shortened version of "ただいま帰りました" meaning "I'm home" or "I just came home".

The exact meaning of "ただいま" is "right now" or "just now". In this context it is written as "只今" in Kanji rather than Hiragana.